# Ubuntu 14.04.1 LTS and OpenSSL

Tags: openssl

Does Ubuntu Ubuntu 14.04.1 LTS have any OpenSSL vulnerabilities in connection with the Heartbleed bug?
I downloaded the ISO today and I am installing it and I would like to know if there are any existing vulnerabilities.

Comment: My question is with regards to the latest version 14.04.1 LTS, and if this version has any vulnerabilities.

Comment: Not a difference, since 14.04 has Heartbleed fixed (14.04.1 is 14.04 with a bunch of updates applied). If you are talking about OpenSSL vulnerabilities in general, do remove the part about being in connection with Heartbleed.  "Any" is a broad term and with 100% confidence I can say that any version of any reasonably large software has vulnerabilities.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As long as you perform the needed updates, Ubuntu 14.04 does not exhibit the Heartbleed bug.
If you get the latest ISO, 14.04.1, you definitely have the latest versions of the packages and are OK with regards to Heartbleed.

Comment: @user277078 please accept this answer, if it was enough, by clicking on the tick next to it.